# Why are some characters still unplayable when clicking on play

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

For some years now there has been an issue with the game: After passing the first few levels (it happened to me with two lvl 18 characters), it becomes impossible to play said characters. What I mean is when presented with the screen showing the characters, clicking on play will not do anything.

**Other lower level characters will react correctly, creating a new character will work as well, but characters with level higher than ~15 are unplayable**

The issue has been know for some years, there are some forum threads about it and alike issues

- [Game won't let me select my character :/](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/951199-star-wars-the-old-republic/68280753)
- [Cannot log onto my main char!!!!!!!](http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?t=526478)
- [Main Character Won't Load! PLEASE HELP!](http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?t=276185)
- [[IMPORTANT] Character Loading Issues](http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?t=713230)

Proposed solutions

- changing firewall settings
- running as administrator
- running in compatibility mode
- repairing install
- waiting after clicking on play
- installing latest drivers

None of them seem to fix the issue. As hinted with the last link, as of january 2014 the devs seem to be aware of the issue. Is there any consistent way of being able to actually play our characters?

Comment: I may be missing something, here, but if a problem effects characters over level 15, but you are still able to play the game on a new character, I find it difficult to believe it could ever be admin rights, firewall, system problems or driver issues. All of those things effect the entire game, and would prevent you from playing at all if anything.

Comment: This issue seems to have been exacerbated recently, it used to be far less common.  After creating a new character, logging into it and then back out, are you able to log into the bugged characters?

Comment: No, I just created a new character, played it for a few hours, but the other character remains unplayable. It is an old character, probably one and a half years old, I wouldn't be able to say if it will still happen with new characters @MatthewRead

Comment: I know right? But sometimes computer do have really strange behaviors, sadly not in this case... @Timelord64

Comment: You might need to contact Customer Service and get them to move your character to a "safe" location (usually Fleet I think).  That was the case for people who couldn't log into their characters for another issue, so it might work.

Comment: I'll definitely try this. I was keeping that as a last resort option..

Comment: [They had downtime to fix this today](http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?p=8299574#edit8299574).  Do your characters work now?

Comment: It certainly did!! How timely of them to do that today :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it no longer applies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentionned by MatthewRead in a [comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/227078/why-are-some-characters-still-unplayable-when-clicking-on-play?noredirect=1#comment307417_227078):

> [they had downtime to fix this today](http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?p=8299574#edit8299574)

---

> All servers will be temporarily unavailable starting at 5AM PDT/12 GMT in order to attempt to address an intermittent login issue.

It was on their side, and as Timelord64 [mentionned](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/227078/why-are-some-characters-still-unplayable-when-clicking-on-play?noredirect=1#comment307274_227078):

> if a problem effects characters over level 15, but you are still able to play the game on a new character, I find it difficult to believe it could ever be admin rights, firewall, system problems or driver issues